# calling two apis async inside my redux saga where I need data from first response to call second api

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have this use case where I need to make two api calls inside redux saga .
I need the repsonse from the first api and use it in my second api call .At the end ,I need to get response of second api call and populate my reducers data .
This is how I did in case of one api call and sent response to my reducers .I am concerned as how things should happen in case of two apis calls because my second api call depends on the data from the first api call .
I am concerned as hownto chain things up in try catch.

```
   export function* fetchSportsFanDetailsHandler() {
      try {
       const { authToken, sportsFanId } = yield select(state => ({
        authToken: state.auth.authToken,
        sportsFanId: state.auth.userId
      }));
const sportsFanDetails = yield call(
  fetchSportsFanDetails,
  sportsFanId,
  authToken
);

    const { name, id, mobile, photo, communicationEmail } =  sportsFanDetails;
    yield put({
  type: FETCH_SPORTS_FAN_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
  response: sportsFanDetails
   });
    } catch (err) {
    const { error } = err.response.data;
     yield put({
     type: FETCH_SPORTS_FAN_DETAILS_ERROR,
      error: error.message
      });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would divide it into two functions, the first one with the first call with its own try/catch and its own error action and returning the request data.

Then I would check that data and when not empty call the second request again with its own try/catch and error handling.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should create seperate method for second api request and then use it in seperate call effect, after you use put effect for first api request then use second call effect with the result from first api response you need.

for example:

````
```
const result = yield call(someMethod, params)
yield put({type: ACTION, result})
const response = yield call(anotherMethod, result)
yield put({type: ACTION_SECOND, response})
```
````